# Exploring Crowd Compression in Unity's NavMeshAgent and Seeking Solutions

Tags: c

I'm encountering a problem while using Unity's NavMeshAgent for crowd movement.
When a large number of objects, representing red and blue teams, move towards a common destination, they tend to cluster together in a single direction instead of spreading out evenly as seen in the following figure:

[image]

This creates an undesirable crowding effect. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or suggestions to address this issue.

Thank you in advance for your help!

This behavior persists even when I disable the pathfinding strategy.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What does this have to do with C? Please edit the tags under your question; it helps attract the right experts.